# How to pass id from link_to to locals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, locals

I m passing the `id` from `link_to` to `locals`. But it is not able to find the result, saying `cannot find article without id`. I need to pass the id for display `articles` in modal.

```
<% @articles.each do |a|%>
<p>
    <%= link_to a.title, {"data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => '#myModal', :id => a.id}%>
</p>
<% end %>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<%= render :partial => "site#show", :locals => {@article => Article.find(params[:id])}%>
</div>
```

In the controller

```
def home
  @articles = Article.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
  @videos = Video.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
end
```

And i m getting the id from the controller. It is not nill. 
The thing is i m able to find the articles in the `block` but not being able to send it to the locals.

Answer (score 0):

this is because params[:id] is null or the record with params[:id] does not exist

In controller you should find where whether the article with the specific id exists if not handle it

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

good practise is to not use finders in views.

Comment: Ive updated with the controller code. i think there is something wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that params[:id] is not nil and while passing locals you should always use symbols and access them as local variables in the partial
e.g.

"site#show", :locals => { :article => Article.find(params[:id])}%>

in _show.html.erb

use it as

Comment: i m using bootstrap's modal.. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: somehow id is already passing but not the one which i need to pass.. `id = #myModal` this is passing.. but m not able to pass the `:id => a.id`